# Retrieve orders info using ETSY Restful api v3

Tags: etsy

I need some informations which are present in the csv file e.g. EtsySoldOrders2021.csv that can be downloaded from the etsy shop dashboard and in which I can find all order for the year 2021. Currently I download the file and reload it manually in google sheet in order to display some data analysis based typically on the order gross amount, order net amount, shipping costs,..... I would be glad to do it through the Restful api v3 , is it possible?

Thanks for any help
Gianfranco

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

You will use the Receipt endpoint to fetch all order data

For details visit: https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/receipt

Answer (score 1):

---

I'm using this endpoint:
https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#operation/getShopReceipts

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/{shop_id}/receipts
```

you can add query params to filter